# How to print the final SQL executed by SimpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am using SimpleJdbcTemplate class from Spring framework to execute SQL queries in a format of prepared statement (question marks). In particular, I am calling queryForInt(String sql, Object... args) method.

Is there any way to print out the final **constructed** query?

Answer (score 0):

The "constructed" query might not even be a valid concept. Not all drivers implement placeholders by interpolating parameters client-side.